# I just installed pytorch on Anaconda but when i try to import it I am getting an error

Tags: anaconda, pytorch

OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found.

[image: here is the image]

Comment: What did you do to install pytorch and which version did you try to install?

Comment: I installed it using this command  conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch  the version that was installed was 1.5.0